# Does Cloud Run support Binary Authorization?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run

If I use [Cloud Run for Anthos](https://cloud.google.com/kuberun/docs/setup), can I use [Binary Authorization](https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization) to secure the container images I deploy to Cloud Run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of mid-may 2021 - Cloud Run (fully managed) now supports Binary Authorization:

https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/run/enabling-binauthz-cloud-run

Answer (score 3):

[Update May 2021]: Cloud Run now [supports Binary Authorization](https://cloud.google.com/binary-authorization/docs/run/enabling-binauthz-cloud-run)

[Original answer]

Cloud Run (fully managed) does not yet support Binary Authorization.

I guess Cloud Run for Anthos does, to be validated.

Comment: Cloud Run for Anthos on VMware (on-premises) does support Binary Authorization.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this - I'm interested whether Cloud Run for Anthos on *GKE* uses bin auth, too.